# how display input fields and required them when selected option with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use a form such as this:

```
<form id="clac" action="#" method="post">
<select onchange="func_type()" name="t_person" id="t_person" class="t_person_class">
    <option value="0" selected>select persons</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>

<input id="t_person_name1"><br/>
<input id="t_person_name2"><br/>
<input id="t_person_name3"><br/>

<input type="submit" value="okGo">
</form>
```

and use script such this for display some input fields when select an option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#t_person_name1').hide();
$('#t_person_name2').hide();
$('#t_person_name3').hide();
$.viewMap = {
'0' : $([]),
'1' : $('#t_person_name1'),
'2' : $('#t_person_name1,#t_person_name2'),
'3' : $('#t_person_name1,#t_person_name2,#t_person_name3')
};

$('#t_person').change(function() {
// hide all
$.each($.viewMap, function() {
    this.hide('500');
});
// show current
$.viewMap[$(this).val()].show('500');
});
})
</script>
```

in works fine, but how when a field display, then this field is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

Instead:

```
$.each($.viewMap, function() {
    this.hide('500');
});
$.viewMap[$(this).val()].show('500');
```

do:

```
$.each($.viewMap, function() {
    this.hide('500').prop('required',false);
});
$.viewMap[$(this).val()].show('500').prop('required',true);
```

View on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jh35L/)

Comment: thanks Mike; works fine, but now how fix it for required fields in IE?